# Why visual c++ (latest) and gcc 12.1 accepted hiding this init capture for lambda, while clang 14.0.0 not? (c++20)

Tags: c++, lambda, compiler-errors, language-lawyer

Case 1

```
int main() {
    int x = 100;
    auto lamb_var = [y = x](){
                    int y = 10;
                    return y + 1;
    }; 

    assert (lamb_var() == 11);

    return 0; 
}
```

in https://godbolt.org/z/hPPParjnz

Both MSVC and GCC accepted shadowing the init-capture, while Clang accused y redefinition on the **compound statement** and throwed compiler error.

However, if we remove the init-capture and make a simple-capture, all compilers accept Shadowing:

Case 2

```
int main() {
    int x = 100;
    auto lamb_var = [x](){
                    int x = 10;
                    return x + 1;
    }; 

    assert (lamb_var() == 11);

    return 0; 
}
```

in https://godbolt.org/z/Gs4cadf5e

---

A simple-capture (case 2) leads to the creation of an attribute in the lambda-associated class, so shadowing should be normal.

From what I [found](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda),the expression *"whose declarative region is the body of the lambda expression"* of the quote below from cppreference could defend the implementation of CLANG ("redefinition"), but I'm not sure.

> A capture with an initializer acts as if it declares and explicitly
> captures a variable declared with type auto, **whose declarative region
> is the body of the lambda expression** (that is, it is not in scope
> within its initializer), except that: [...]

**Who is right in implementation (GCC and MSVC or Clang), and how to understand this citation of cppreference?**

---

Related questions

[Lambda capture and parameter with same name - who shadows the other? (clang vs gcc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42088015/lambda-capture-and-parameter-with-same-name-who-shadows-the-other-clang-vs-g?rq=1)

Comment: You sure that `assert` doesn't simply vanish its usage? That's what it does unless you have proper macro defined.

Comment: Here's an example without the assert: https://godbolt.org/z/48rsY6MqW. Clang seems to allow the shadowing if you add an extra scope block, suggesting it is taking a strict interpretation of the standard where `y=x` is treated as a declaration in the body of the lambda. However, it also seems declarative regions in general are somewhat of a grey area (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684431/what-is-the-actual-definition-of-declarative-region). I expect the standard is really trying to say that `y` is not defined within the capture itself (you cannot use `z=y`, for instance).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that *clang is correct in rejecting snippet 1 and accepting snippet 2* because in the first case the non-static data member is **named** `y` while in the second case the non-static data member is **unnamed**.

##### Case 1

Here we consider snippet 1:

```
int main() {
    int x = 100;
    auto lamb_var = [y = x](){  //the data member is "named" y
                    int y = 10; //error because we're defining y for second time 
                    return y + 1;
    }; 

    assert (lamb_var() == 11);

    return 0; 
}
```

Now, from [expr.prim.lambda#capture-6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.lambda#capture-6):

> An init-capture without ellipsis **behaves as if it declares and explicitly captures a variable of the form** `auto init-capture ;` **whose declarative region is the lambda-expression's compound-statement**, except that:

(emphasis mine)

This seems to indicate that the non-static data member **has a name** which in your given example is `y`. Now, by writing `int y = 10;` we're providing a redefinition of the same named variable `y` in the same declarative region and hence the error.

---

Note that we will get the same error(as expected due to the reason explained above), if we replace `[y=x]` with `[x=x]` and `int y =10;` with `int x = 10;`  as shown below:

```
int main() {
    int x = 100;
    auto lamb_var = [x = x](){  //data member "named" x
                    int x = 10; //this will give same error 
                    return x + 1;
    }; 

    assert (lamb_var() == 11);

    return 0; 
}
```

##### Case 2

Here we consider the snippet 2:

```
int main() {
    int x = 100;
    auto lamb_var = [x](){         //data member is unnamed
                    int x = 10;   //ok because we're defining an int variable with "name" x for the first time in this region
                    return x + 1;
    }; 

    assert (lamb_var() == 11);

    return 0; 
}
```

Here from [expr.prim.lambda#capture-10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.lambda#capture-10):

> For each entity captured by copy, an **unnamed non-static data member** is declared in the closure type. The declaration order of these members is unspecified....

(emphasis mine)

In this case, the non-static data member is **unnamed** and so writing `int x = 10;` is not a redefinition error because we're definining a variable **named** `x` for the first time in this region.