# What is the difference between lambda capture [&args...] and [...args = std::forward<Args>(args)]

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++20, variadic

I'm writing a simple game with Entity Component System. One of my components is `NativeScriptComponent`. It contains the instance of my script. The idea is that I can create my `NativeScriptComponent` anytime and then `Bind` to it any class implementing `Scriptable` interface. After that my game's OnUpdate function will automatically instantiate all scripts in my game and will call their OnUpdate function.

My scripts can have their own, different constructors so I need to forward all the arguments to them when I bind my script.

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

struct Scriptable
{
    virtual void OnUpdate() {};
};
struct MyScript : Scriptable 
{ 
    MyScript(int n) : value(n) {}
    void OnUpdate() override {cout << value;} 
    int value;
};

struct NativeScriptComponent
{
    unique_ptr<Scriptable> Instance;
    function<unique_ptr<Scriptable>()> Instantiate;

    template<typename T, typename ... Args>
    void Bind(Args&&... args)
    {
        // (A)
        Instantiate = [&args...]() { return make_unique<T>(forward<Args>(args)...);  };
        // (B) since C++20
        Instantiate = [...args = forward<Args>(args)]() { return make_unique<T>(args...);  };
    }
};

int main()
{
    NativeScriptComponent nsc;
    nsc.Bind<MyScript>(5);
    
    // [..] Later in my game's OnUpdate function:
    if (!nsc.Instance)
        nsc.Instance = nsc.Instantiate();
    nsc.Instance->OnUpdate(); // prints: 5

    return 0;
}
```

**1) What is the difference between option A and B**

```cpp
Instantiate = [&args...]() { return make_unique<T>(forward<Args>(args)...);  };
```

vs

```cpp
Instantiate = [...args = forward<Args>(args)]() { return make_unique<T>(args...);  };
```

2. Why can't I use `forward<Args>(args)` inside `make_unique` in option B?
3. Are both A and B perfectly-forwarded?

Comment: Related: [capture [y = x\] vs [x\]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73273317/12002570).

Comment: Without digging into it, I'm fairly certain that a capturing a reference requires an explicit `&` somewhere in its vicinity. Even if `std::forward` forwards a reference, it will look around, not see a `&` anywhere, and turn itself into a pumpkin, err... a copy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For added completeness, there's more things you can do. As pointed out in the other answer:

```cpp
[&args...]() { return make_unique<T>(forward<Args>(args)...);  };
```

This captures all the arguments by reference, which could lead to dangling. But those references *are* properly forwarded in the body.

---

```cpp
[...args=forward<Args>(args)]() { return make_unique<T>(args...);  };
```

This forwards all the arguments into the lambda, `args` internally is a pack of *values*, not references. This passes them all as *lvalues* into `make_unique`.

---

```cpp
[...args=forward<Args>(args)]() mutable { return make_unique<T>(move(args)...);  };
```

Given that, as above, `args` is a pack of values and we're creating a `unique_ptr` anyway, we probably should `std::move` them into `make_unique`. Note that the lambda has its own internal `args` here, so moving them does not affect any of the lvalues that were passed into this function.

---

```cpp
[args=tuple<Args...>(forward<Args>(args)...)]() mutable {
    return std::apply([](Args&&... args){
        return std::make_unique<T>(forward<Args>(args)...);
    }, std::move(args));
};
```

The most fun option. Before we'd either capture *all* the arguments by reference, or forward *all* the args (copying the lvalues and moving the rvalues). But there's a third option: we could capture the lvalues by reference and move the rvalues. We can do that by explicitly capturing a tuple and forwarding into it (note that for lvalues, the template parameter is `T&` and for rvalues it's `T` - so we get rvalues by value).

Once we have the tuple, we `apply` on it internally - which gives us `Args&&...` back (note the `&&` and that this is not a generic lambda, doesn't need to be).

This is an improvement over the previous version in that we don't need to copy lvalues -- or perhaps it's worse because now we have more opportunity for dangling.

A comparison of the four solutions:

| option | can dangle? | lvalue | rvalue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `&args...` | both lvalues and rvalues | 1 copy | 1 move |
| `...args=FWD(args)` and `args...` | no | 2 copies | 1 move, 1 copy |
| `...args=FWD(args)` and `move(args)...` | no | 1 copy, 1 move | 2 moves |
| `args=tuple<Args...>` | lvalues | 1 copy | 2 moves |

Answer (score 1):

A captures the arguments by reference and then perfectly forwards into `make_unique`. Unfortunately by that point the references are (probably) dangling, so calling `Instantiate` in your example has undefined behaviour.

B perfectly forwards the arguments into the data members of the closure object, then copies those data members into `make_unique`. You can't forward here without marking the lambda `mutable`, because the body of a lambda is a `const` member function of the closure object.

A can't forward rvalues, the references to them dangle. B can't forward lvalues, it does a copy.

If you only want to instantiate one `Scriptable`, then you can mark the lambda in `B` as `mutable`, and move in there. If you want to construct multiple `Scriptable`s, you will have to do some copying.